# Computing the intersection of two lattices

Tags: lattice-crypto

Given two lattices $L_1$ and $L_2$ represented by bases $B_1$ and $B_2$, is there an efficient algorithm to compute $L_1\cap L_2$?

I can show, I think, that if $\gcd(\det(B_1),\det(B_2))=1$, then $B_1adj(B_1)B_2$ generates $L_1\cap L_2$, but I'm interested in lattices whose volumes have greater GCDs.

A follow-up question is if there is an efficient algorithm to represent the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2+v$ for some $v\notin L_1,L_2$.

Comment: for the intersection I think there is a mention here https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//classes/wi10/cse206a/lec2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The answer to both questions is yes, and they both follow immediately by the link in the comments (even though the fact that the second follows from the link was not mentioned).

The trick is that lattice duality interchanges sums and intersections, e.g.

$$(L_0+L_1)^* = L_0^*\cap L_1^*$$

There are some conditions on this I believe, and I've written an answer on here somewhere on precisely this topic ~2 years ago (I saw it within the last day here, but don't want to hunt for a link currently).

You combine this with the fact that we have a very efficient representation of $L_0 + L_1$.
In particular, you can

1. Concatenate their bases, then
2. Compute the Hermite Normal Form (HNF) of the resulting generating set

to get a basis for $L_0 + L_1$. By duality, this can also be used to get a basis for the intersection.

What about $L_0 \cap (v+L_1)$? Just view $L_1' = v + L_1$ as another lattice, use the HNF to compute its basis, then use the duality trick to compute the basis of the intersection, e.g. it immediately follows from this general technique.

It's worth mentioning that things get trickier if you cannot view $v + L_1$ as a lattice, for example if it is not discrete. You can see this in 1D with the "lattice" $\mathbb{Z} + \pi\mathbb{Z}$. Provided things like the relevant sums and intersections result in lattices (which will always happen if you require that $q\mathbb{Z}^n\subseteq L, L'\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$, perhaps for large $q$) you're fine though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure about the second point though, since $L+v$ is not a lattice (for example it does not contain $0$). I played around with the dual of it and couldn't find a nice representation. Is there some way to make it look enough like a lattice that this works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can view it as a lattice embedded in one-dimensional higher space. This is similar to how an affine space can be viewed as a linear space in one dimension higher, and conceptually similar to [Kannen's embedding](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/ch18.pdf) to reduce CVP to SVP. The main annoyance with these types of things is that the embedding is highly non-unique, and (e.g. when practically trying to apply things like Kannen's) you'll get different performance depending on which particular embedding (for Kannen's, parameterized by which scaling factor)

Comment: Concretely, I'm suggesting that you view $L + v$ as a $n$-dimensional "slice" of an $n+1$ dimensional lattice. These also typically behave well with duality (it is typically called the "projection slice" theorem, but I am mostly seeing references to this for lattices where one projects/slices through linear subspaces, while your setting would be an affine subspace. Maybe that kills the whole idea.)

Comment: How much are those notes reliable? https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//classes/wi10/cse206a/lec1.pdf `Other lattices can be obtained from` (page 1) there conflicting two base definition; $B \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$

Comment: they are reliable. That is likely a symptom of there being two conflicting notations for lattices, namely as the image of $x\mapsto Bx$ and the image of $x^t\mapsto x^t B$ ("column notation" vs "row notation"), so it is easy to mix up the order of the two, as in row notation you have rank $k$ dimension $n$ lattice having basis $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, and in column notation you have it in $\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$.

Comment: It is what I was expecting, however, the lecturer should not make a pit for their target audience. ( note that  you should add @nickname if you really want to inform the commenter. Otherwise, I've to check that there is something for me to see this)

Comment: @kelalaka weird, I get notifications even without being @'ed. And I agree there are some inconsistencies (along the lines of what you have noticed, or for example in section 3 of that document $k\mapsto m$ becomes the lattice rank, before in section 4 $m\mapsto k$ again). It would be better if all of these small issues were ironed out, but this feels like asking for each set of lecture notes to be of similar quality to a book. The annoyance in ironing out these details is generally why people write lecture notes rather than books in the first place.

Comment: If you are the asker or answerer, you will get it always. Either the students are not reading or they are not updated. I saw a very badly written book on Birkhauser - which I don't remember the name of the book-  on which my professor surprised since within a few pages I've found many mistakes. Ah, those days.